# How to read xhtml using XML DOM?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, dom, xhtml

I have the following .xhtml file: https://pastebin.com/GUykneib

It's essentially a bash wget on a website in a shell script, and I need to extract rows of information on certain stocks. Here is an example:
[image]

This is my Python script:

```
import sys
import xml.dom.minidom

document = xml.dom.minidom.parse(sys.argv[1])

tableElements = document.getElementsByTagName('table')
for tr in tableElements[2].getElementsByTagName('tr'):
    data = []
    for td in tr.getElementsByTagName('td'):
        for a in td.getElementsByTagName('a'):
            for node in a.childNodes:
                if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
                    data.append(node.nodeValue)
    print(data)
```

However, when I pass the .xhtml file when running the program, only an empty list is printed (only once, shouldn't it at least be 5 times since I'm traversing 5 columns?) I'm new to XML DOM, where is my mistake?

Comment: The line `for a in td.getElementsByTagName('td'):` should be `for a in td.getElementsByTagName('a'):`, otherwise you'd be looking for td elements inside td elements. There are none of those in the XHTML file. Also, you want the third table, `tableElements[2]` instead of `tableElements[0]`; you'd be better off looking for class `mdcTable` instead of any table.

Comment: Seems like I made stupid mistakes more than anything, but the only issue I have now is accessing the later columns. For example, the "volume" column is denoted by <td>'s, yet when I try to iterate over td.childNodes, I get no output.

Comment: Only the first <td> in each row contains an <a>.